# Losing most of download/upload speed from router to wireless devices. Prevents decent online gaming for Wii

Tags: wireless-networking, download

We used to have a Netgear router provided by Sky with many wireless devices connected. We never had any issues connecting to the internet, but I believe we had it upgraded after a while. However we changed to the Netgear DGN1000 router, and Orange are now our Internet providers. Ever since we changed to Orange and got the new router, we have had many problems connecting to the internet. It would randomly cut us off at times, and the download/upload speeds are just ridiculously poor. Here is a list of connected devices, just to show you exactly how many devices are connected:

- Xbox 360
- Playstation 3
- Nintendo Wii
- 2 iPod Touch's
- 2 Laptops
- Printer (ALL wireless)

The Xbox 360 gets the best connection out of everything. Currently, our download speed from Orange to our router is 12.3Mbps, upload speed 1.02Mbps. From the router to my laptop, it is roughly 2.6Mbps, and perhaps less on some devices. We are losing 10 MB of download speed, but I am clueless as to why we are losing so much. It is preventing me from playing Nintendo Wii games online the most, especially Mario Kart Wii, my favourite. When online, there is a 'Please Wait' screen before races, it tends to stay on that screen until eventually I disconnect.

We have phoned Orange countless times, restored factory settings, done everything they asked of us, we even got sent 2 new routers (the same one), and this 3rd one still has the same problems. We use the Mixed WPA-TSK+WPA2-TSK security option, and the router is downstairs, with most other things being upstairs, nothing directly above the router also. It's connected to the secondary ADSL port/modem, as the primary is right by the front door. I am sure there is some interference, but unsure as to how much. Most of the time, everything can connect fine. I really badly want to improve the connection for the Wii mostly, as I want to be able to play it online more.

Comment: What radio type and what channel is the router on?  Have you tried a different channel?

Comment: It is currently on channel 1, I have also tried channels 6 and 11 before. On all these channels the same problems happen. What do you mean by radio type, by the way?

Comment: @Shinrai (Forgot to notify on that comment^) Oh, I have also just bought a wireless usb adapter which I'm setting up now. I don't exactly know if it'll improve my wireless connectivity, as we have wireless already.

Comment: I mean, is it an 802.11g network? 802.11n?

Comment: @Shinrai It's any supported, but i think the wireless devices may only be able run at 802.11g speeds. Could be wrong though.

Comment: Thanks for further detail.  Unfortunately this isn't my area of expertise, but I'm enough of an expert to know these are useful details to have. ;)